# Outlook Script To Check for Text In Body

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a script we use. What I need a portion of this to do is look for a link embedded in the e-mail and skip the script if it finds it. However, it's not working:

```
If Item.Class = "43" Then
If InStr(Item.Body, "https://mywebsite.local/TEMP*") = 1 Then
GoTo NonEmailError
End If
```

So after the TEMP is actually some random characters. It doesn't appear the wild card works in the above. Is there a way to use a wildcard in this type of statement? What can I do here?

Comment: If it really is the case that the wild card isn't working, couldn't you just take the * out? The one unwanted side effect it might have is that it'll find the 'root' directory: "https://mywebsite.local/TEMP" as well as "https://mywebsite.local/TEMP*".

Comment: Wildcards work with Like: `If Lcase(Item.Body) Like "https://mywebsite.local/temp*" Then...`   Assuming the http is at the beginning of the body text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, having commented already, I suspect your problem is in fact that you're testing that InStr returns 1. This will probably fix your problem:

```
If InStr(Item.Body, "https://mywebsite.local/TEMP") > 0 Then
```

Edit: you'll still need to remove the wildcard.

Comment: And you, my friend, are Untalented. But seriously, glad to help :)