# outlook : Save attachments automatically into multiple folders

Tags: vba, outlook-2010

I found a script online and it works for auto saving 1 attachment from 1 sender.
I need to adjust the script to automatically download attachments from multiple senders into separate different folders. I tried duplicating the code and adding "findinMail" for it to recognize the targeted subject for downloading. I failed miserably. Can anyone help me ? PS: I don't know anything about coding and not a programmer on the professional level. Trying to piece everything together.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
Dim findInMail As String

findInMail = "Abc"
sSaveFolder = "c:\temp\abc\"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next

findInMail = "xyz"
sSaveFolder = "c:\temp\xyz\"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlook Script To Check for Text In Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831012/outlook-script-to-check-for-text-in-body)

Comment: If InStr(MItem.Subject, "some string") > 0 Then

Comment: `failed miserably` does not describe what happens when you run the code. ... please include a description of the problem that you are trying to eliminate

Comment: `findInMail` is the name of a string variable. it does not do anything other than stores a text string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through VBA & Macros.
[How To Save All Attachments From Multiple Emails To Folder In Outlook](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1166-outlook-save-all-attachments.html)

Refer this and add extra code to copy download folder contents to another folder.

Comment: I saw this before I posted and I do not wish to delete the attachments on the emails. I tried removing the 'delete strings' and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/89022/save-attachments-from-many-emails-at-once-in-outlook)

In short, there are already a lot of utilities to get this done, Like sumit shared the answer, there is already a ready tool available, there's also compiled code.

PS: Why to reinvent the wheel?

[Nirsoft's outlook attach view](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_attachment.html)

[Solution for your problem by MS](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Save-attachments-from-5b6bf54b)